# Can I replace a failed RAID disk with a used spare?

Tags: windows-server-2000, raid5

I have a Dell PowerEdge 2650 with hardware Raid - two drives in Raid 1, four drives in Raid 5.  Originally, all six drives were the same size, but a while back I upgraded the Raid 5 array and kept the original drives as spares for the Raid 1 array.  One of the Raid 1 drives has now failed, and I want to use the spare that I kept that used to be part of the Raid 5 array.  Can I just insert the spare drive into the slot the failed drive came out of -- will the system accept it as a new replacement in the Raid 1 array, or will it be confused by the old data that's already on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server is up and running when you swap it over it'll be just fine, it'll recognise it as a new drive and start the R1 rebuild. I'm glad you asked, always makes sense to check if you aren't comfortable by you're fine this time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! That was what I expected, but I wanted to be sure before going ahead.  It's happily rebuilding now.

Comment: Great news, glad to help, sometimes we all just need someone to confirm we're on the right track - that's what SF is often best at :)